# In OctoPrint when receiving temperature data (M105) what is T0?

Tags: octoprint

I've setup OctoPrint with the goal to log temperature data of my hot end. So, I've enable serial logging and examined the serial log file.

**The Output for an example line is as follows:**

> Send: M105
>
> Recv: ok T:20.7 /50.0 B:20.0 /0.0 T0:20.7 /0.0 @:0 B@:0

**So, from what I understand:**

T = Thermistor temp of hot end °C

*In the example, current temp is 20.7 and target temp is 50.0*

B = temp of bed °C

*In the example, current temp is 20.0 and target temp is 0.0*

But what is T0?

Or the @ and B@?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` is the selected tool, `T0` is the first hotend tool. If you only have one hotend, `T` and `T0` are exactly the same.

Do note that G-codes are described on the [G-code wiki page](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code), for [`M105`](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M105:_Get_Extruder_Temperature) you can find:

> The parameters mean the following:
>    - T, T0, ..., Tn - extruder temperature. In a single extruder setup, only T will be reported. Some firmware variants will report no T0 in multi extruder setups - in that case T is to be considered the temperature of the first tool. Otherwise, T should be considered the temperature of the currently selected tool (which will be repeated in one of the Tn entries)
>    - B - bed temperature
>    - C - chamber temperature
>    - @ - Hotend power (Prusa only)
>    - B@ - Bed power (Prusa only)
>    - P - PINDAv2 actual (Prusa MK2.5/s MK3/s only)
>    - A - Ambient actual (Prusa MK3/s only)